# open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, open-basedir

I have been having trouble using a file upload script on my server - came to the conclusion that this was because PHP was being run on Apache Module so reconfigured PHP to run as FastCGI.

Unfortunately now when I try to upload a file via uploadify I get the error

> Warning: move_uploaded_file()[function.move-uploaded-file] open_base_dir restrictions in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/uploads/filename.txt) is not within the allowed path(s):(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs:/tmp) in .....

It then refers me to line 32 of my script which reads:

```
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
```

$tempFile is as follows:

```
$tempFile = str_replace(" ","",$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']);
```

I have tried altering my vhost.conf file in numerous ways bit without success - it currently stands as

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs>
    <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
            php_admin_flag engine off
            php_admin_flag safe_mode on
            php_admin_value open_basedir none
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            php_admin_flag engine on
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            php_admin_value open_basedir none
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I seem to be going round in circles - it seems that the tmp directory is not being found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's your server and you can actually mess around with configuration, you can turn off the `open_basedir` in your php.ini, reload PHP and try if it works. `safe_mode` should be turned off in PHP by default as this option causes only problems.

Or you can try following:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs>
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/:/tmp/:/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/uploads/"
</Directory>
```

Same can apply for the php.ini if you decide to set the config there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I seem to have got around the problem with your first suggestion